# How to pass environment bash variables into json using jq

Tags: bash, jq

I have json like this

```
{
   "Subject": {
       "Data": "Value",
       "Charset": "UTF-8"
   },
   "Body": {
       "Text": {
           "Data": "Value",
           "Charset": "UTF-8"
       },
       "Html": {
           "Data": "Data example",
           "Charset": "UTF-8"
       }
   }
}
```

And I need pass into this variables from bash script like this:

```
{
   "Subject": {
       "Data": "Value $value1",
       "Charset": "UTF-8"
   },
   "Body": {
       "Text": {
           "Data": "Value $value2",
           "Charset": "UTF-8"
       },
       "Html": {
           "Data": "Data example",
           "Charset": "UTF-8"
       }
   }
}
```

I tried with this:

```
jq -n --arg value1 test --arg value2 -f message.jq
```

but this ignore my $variables from message.jq, when I delete "" (quotes in message.jq close to $variable then working by json is destroyed I need quotes with variables.

Comment: Post your script file `message.jq`

Comment: The correct syntax is `\($value1)`.